# JAVA: Extract Footer Images from a docx document

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx

I've a task of extracting all the images from a docx file. I am ussing the snippet below for the same. I am using the *Apache POI* api for the same.

```
`File file = new File(InputFileString);
 FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
 //FileInputStream fs=new FileInputStream(src);
  //create office word 2007+ document object to wrap the word file
  XWPFDocument doc1x=new XWPFDocument(fs);
  //get all images from the document and store them in the list piclist
  List<XWPFPictureData> piclist=doc1x.getAllPictures();
  //traverse through the list and write each image to a file
  Iterator<XWPFPictureData> iterator=piclist.iterator();
  int i=0;
  while(iterator.hasNext()){
   XWPFPictureData pic=iterator.next();
   byte[] bytepic=pic.getData();
   BufferedImage imag=ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytepic));
          ImageIO.write(imag, "jpg", new File("C:/imagefromword"+i+".jpg"));
          i++;
  }`
```

However, this code cannot detect any images which are in the footer or header section of the document.

I've extensively used my google skills and couldn't come up with anything useful.

> Is there anyway to capture the image file in the footer section of the
>   docx file?

Comment: Did you try calling [getAllPictures](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFHeaderFooter.html#getAllPictures()) on the header and on the footer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no expert on `Apache POI` issues, but a simple search came up with [this](http://www.concretepage.com/apache-api/apache-poi-xwpf-read-ms-word-docx-header-footer-paragraph-table-example) code:

```
package com.concretepage;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.model.XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFFooter;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFHeader;
public class ReadDOCXHeaderFooter {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     try {
     FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("D:/docx/read-test.docx");
     XWPFDocument xdoc=new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(fis));
     XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy policy = new XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy(xdoc);
     //read header
     XWPFHeader header = policy.getDefaultHeader();
     System.out.println(header.getText());
     //read footer
     XWPFFooter footer = policy.getDefaultFooter();
     System.out.println(footer.getText());
     } catch(Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
     } 
  }
}
```

And the documentation page of [XWPFHeaderFooter](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFHeaderFooter.html) (which is the direct father class of the [XWPFFooter](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFFooter.html) class in the above example...) shows the same [getAllPictures](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFHeaderFooter.html#getAllPictures()) method you used to iterate over all the pictures in the documents body.

I on mobile, so I haven't really tested anything - but it seems straight-forward enough to work.

Good luck!